# How do I fix a garage door opener light that loosens in its socket?

Tags: lighting, garage-door-opener

The light on my garage door opener keeps getting loose in the light socket, causing it to not work. Giving it a slight turn to tighten it fixes it temporarily, but it comes loose again within a week or so. I'm assuming it's the vibration of the opener that's causing the problem.

How can I prevent the light bulb from coming loose in the socket?

Answer (score 7):

First unplug the opener. Now look in the light socket. See if the small metal tab at the bottom is nearly flat. Carefully pull it up a little bit so it applys more spring tension to the bulb. Also, they used to sell "rough service" Incandescent bulbs for openers, but I have had OK luck with compact fluorescents.

Comment: Turn the power off before you do this, at the breaker. The switch is not enough - depending on how it's wired part of the socket may still be hot. The few seconds spent turning off the breaker is worth it to not be electrocuted.

Comment: Don't worry about shutting off the breaker, if you unplug the Opener. I've never known an electrical charge to cross to the "unplugged" opener, unless it's in a cartoon or on Ghost Hunters!

Comment: Most openers are connected by a standard receptacle/plug, where David's comment is accurate. If yours is hardwired, then turn off the breaker, like gregmac says.

Comment: On all 4 of my light sockets, the contact at the bottom of the socket AND the bulb were corroded. This was only after 4 years. I used sandpaper on both the socket contact and the bottom of the bulb and now have a great connection.

Answer (score 2):

Try a different brand of light bulbs.  Another brand might have a slightly larger base or have a little bit more friction to prevent the bulb from loosening due to the friction.

Answer (score 0):

Take a pair of pliers and gently squeeze the socket to tighten it. This worked like a charm on my unit.**Be gentle**, as you don't want to break the components inside the socket.

Answer (score -2):

Try wrapping the threads on the light bulb with Teflon tape. That will give the bulb a snugger fit in the socket.

Comment: Won't the Teflon tape break the electrical connection between the bulb and socket?

Comment: Would something conductive like a piece of aluminum foil do the trick?

Comment: The teflon tape is safe.  The foil... could cause sparking and overheating.  Obviously you don't wrap the ENTIRE thread.